# SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Authorization Required

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am using third party SOAP API to get users details

```
$wsdl = 'https://sample.ifuture.com/sites/sample.xxxx.com/api/isession.php?wsdl';

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array ( 'username'=>'testusername', 'password'=>'testpassword'));

print_r($client->__getFunctions());
```

When I use `SoapClient()` I am successfully connect to WSDL, last statement return the function list of the WSDL.

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => boolean iLoggedOn(string $session)
    [1] => boolean iLogOff(string $session)
    [2] => boolean iLogOn(string $session, string $username, string $password)
    [3] => boolean iPasswd(string $session, string $username, string $password)
    [4] => list(boolean $return, string $message) iSync(string $username, string $action, string $values)
)
```

Now I am trying to use the SOAP `__Call()` to invoke soap method

```
$param = array(
            "sessionid" =>"12345678900987654321abcisfetul12",
            "username" =>"test",
            "password"=>"test");        
        $client->__Call('iLogOn', $param);
```

The execution of above  statement generates an error as mentioned below

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Authorization Required in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/saop/index.php:79 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://sample....', 'https://sample....', 1, 0) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/saop/index.php(79): SoapClient->__call('iLogOn', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/saop/index.php on line 79
```

Looking forward for appropriate solution.

Comment: try to use [`__soapCall()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php), `__call()` is deprecated

Comment: I have tried with __soapCall  but it return same error.

Comment: mhh, does `__getFunctions()` works if you don't give username and password to `SoapClient()` ?

Comment: Yes, __getFunctions() is working without username and password

Comment: Is there any documentation for the app you try to use ?

Comment: @Bob0t I find solution, I have made mistake in pass parameter while authentication. Let me show you. $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array ( 'username'=>'testusername', 'password'=>'testpassword')); I have to use login instead of username

Comment: Ah well, good point :)